# How to perform in-memory test of HttpClientHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm writing some in-memory integration tests by passing a `HttpServer` instance directly to `HttpClient`. How can I also wire up a `HttpClientHandler`?

```
Establish ctx = () =>
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Default", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "values", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CompressionHandler());

    var server = new HttpServer(config)
    {
        InnerHandler = new DecompressionHandler()
    };
    client = new HttpClient(server);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing a client handler I had to actually set the `HttpServer` as the **inner** handler:

```
var server = new HttpServer(config);

var handler = new DecompressionHandler
{
    InnerHandler = server
};

client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Ben, I'm trying to do this as well (need to use the handler to remove NTLM authentication being passed into my tests), but don't see an InnerHandler property on HttpClientHandler. Did you do something fancy with your DecompressionHandler class? Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting the NTLM authentication? Surely it would be easier to pass in a `HttpConfiguration` that excludes any authentication?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain handlers:

```
var handler = new HttpServer(config)
{
    InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

More info (surprise! :-) at asp.net - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers

Comment: This is what I tried but the client handler is not invoked. I've updated my question with complete set up code.