# How do I get cookies from HttpClientHandler.CookieContainer while using Web API self-hosting?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, self-hosting

I'm trying to write an integration test for a Web API method that returns a cookie. Based on this question, I believe I need to set the CookieContainer of an HttpClientHandler.

[HttpClient Not Saving Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983992/httpclient-not-saving-cookies)

Then, based on this question, I think I need to set this HttpClientHandler as the InnerHandler for my instance of HttpServer so that I can chain the handlers.

[How to perform in-memory test of HttpClientHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564419/how-to-perform-in-memory-test-of-httpclienthandler)

The problem is that I'm still finding that the CookieContainer is empty. I have an Assert that verifies that there is a header in the response that includes the cookie that I'm expecting. Here is my code:

```
        // Set up in-memory hosting of Web API
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieJar,
            UseCookies = true                
        };
        var httpServer = new HttpServer(config)
        {
            InnerHandler = httpClientHandler
        };

        const string loginUrl = "http://localhost/api/authentication/login";
        var uri = new Uri(loginUrl);

        var client = new HttpClient(httpServer) { BaseAddress = uri };

        var response =
            client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri,
                new LoginMessage {Email = UserEmail, Password = Password},
                CancellationToken.None).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginResponse>().Result;
        Assert.IsTrue(response.Headers.Contains("Set-Cookie"));
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, httpClientHandler.CookieContainer.Count);
```

That last Assert on the number of items in the CookieContainer fails. I also tried calling `httpClientHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri)`, but the resulting cookie collection still contains zero elements.

I also tried explicitly chaining my client handlers, but saw no difference in behavior.

```
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieJar,
            UseCookies = true
        };
        var httpServer = new HttpServer(config);

        var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(httpClientHandler, httpServer);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in trying to retrieve these cookies? The cookie that I see in the response header looks like this:

```
Temp=E4C4947BAB708D089C636B4A5BDA094A10C8B1D66347EBD96629CB9BDB589822198A09BCBBE22C13D07AFC4D4C3C91E78C08BECFC9CC03BEE881858A1B4752EDC1BB1E604B819FBAFE34776B6F46B78ADCD2421F8125A395784981BFF22CEBE19DB228158E85B5786279E55D4114B72E50098B2374C23A43B7C89EBA30F771C54E1D98A6B1CD315D1FB8623E8E97E41FE4279479B49D0A948E2752CA09BD17FF7B52764E96EA43DB9E98D7CEBD8A73C9547A696C170CFC9B6F75CA23B881ED9675C2344A2A16BEF2DFD70DBA723FB62578E7779ECADCF11347B22199DAC8FA6A; expires=Thu, 22 May 2014 01:37:36 GMT; path=/
```

Comment: If you look at the accepted answer to the question you linked to you will see that to chain handlers you need to set the HttpServer to the inner handler. HttpClientHandler is not a delegating handler so it will not be possible to chain it.  I think you are just going to have to check the header and not try and use the CookieJar.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks for clarifying that. It wasn't clear to me which one had to be the inner handler, though I did notice that HttpClientHandler wasn't a delegating handler. Is there an implementation of a delegating handler that can handle the cookies, or can you point me towards resource that may help me implement one?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comment I received on the original question from Darrel Miller, it appears that the only way to handle this is if we have a delegating handler that uses the HttpServer as the inner handler.

I ended up building my own CookieDelegateHandler that looks like this:

```
    public class CookieDelegateHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return
                base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(responseToCompleteTask
                    =>
                {
                    var result = responseToCompleteTask.Result;
                    var cookieHeaders = result.Headers.Where(pair => pair.Key == "Set-Cookie");
                    foreach (var value in cookieHeaders.SelectMany(header => header.Value))
                    {
                        CookieContainer.SetCookies(request.RequestUri, value);
                    }
                    return result;
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        }
    }
```

With this implementation, I can instantiate the HttpClient like this:

```
    var client = new HttpClient(new CookieDelegateHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
        InnerHandler = new HttpServer(config)
    });
```

The delegating handler's continuation is executed, and the cookies are added to the CookieContainer.

I'd welcome any other ideas on how to solve this without this custom delegating handler, or comments on whether there are problems in my solution.

Comment: Having this type of functionality as separate delegating handlers is the best option longer term.  When we start to move to HTTP/2 we will not be able to use HttpClientHandler any more and the less stuff will need to be re-implemented the better.  Same goes for redirects.  There is a question somewhere on SO where I implemented my own redirect handler.  And decompression, and caching.